# würde + Infinitiv Perfekt (Konjunktiv II)

Tags: sentence-structure, german-to-english, subjunctive, perfect-tense

1.Could you please look at this  [Konjunktiv II](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Konjugation_Konjunktiv_II) and help me make sense of it ? i am confused about comparing tenses and when to use which one.

2.Second question is about " würde+infinitiv Perfekt" construction. According to the table here conjugation subjunctive II,

it refers to the future, although it is a substitute form for the subjunctive II pluperfect. It is used instead of the subjunctive II pluperfect, rarely, especially colloquially.

Is the construction just a substitute for the subjunctive II past perfect and only the name of the construction adds some confusion ( Konjunktiv Präteritum is used to express the present and future) or can it still be used to express the future?

it is a translation of a question which i need help understanding the question itself, i find it very confusing, please help me.

Comment: Sorry, but the explanations of the Konjunktiv at the site you linked are the most complicated ones that I have ever seen. More importantly, the explanations, if taken literally, are simply wrong.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  Thank you

Comment: It seems your question is missing a link for “the table here conjugation subjunctive II”.

Comment: @mach, the link is given in the first sentence.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Maybe it is the same link. It seems to me, though, that the question is comparing that first link to some other analysis. Also, there is a gap in the question where I think such a comparative link ought to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think these things happen when a bad analysis is explained in a bad way.

I doubt whether the *würde* + past participle + *haben/sein* («er würde geschlafen haben»/«sie würde gegangen sein») is anything other than a *würde* periphrasis of the *hätte/wäre* + past participle construction. I believe the *hätte/wäre* + past participle construction should normally be preferred («er hätte geschlafen»/«sie wäre gegangen»). The reason is that the *würde* periphrasis is not normally used with the auxiliary verbs *haben* and *sein*. Instead, the regular conjunctive preterite (or "II") is normally used for these verbs, that is, the forms *hätte* and *wäre*.

Calling *würde* + past participle + *haben/sein* a «Futur II Konjunktiv II» seems like a particularly bad analysis to me. Instead, I would call it a periphrastic form of the perfect of the conjunctive preterite:

- The conjunctive preterite means forms like *hätte/wäre/schliefe* etc. (contrasting with the conjunctive present *habe/sei/schlafe*). It mainly expresses the irrealis mood.
- The perfect means auxiliary (*haben* or *sein*) + past participle. It expresses that an action has completed or finished. For the perfect of the conjunctive preterite, the auxiliary takes the conjunctive preterite form, that is, *hätte* or *wäre* + past participle.
- The periphrasis of the conjunctive preterite means replacing a conjunctive preterite form by *würde* + infinitive.

To sum it up, there are two forms of the conjunctive preterite, the non-perfect form (without auxiliary) and the perfect form (with auxiliary). In both forms, the finite verb can be replaced by a periphrastic construction with *würde*:

|  | Non-periphrastic form | Periphrasis with *würde* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Non-perfect** | er schliefe/sie ginge | er würde schlafen/sie würde gehen |
| **Perfect** | er hätte geschlafen/sie wäre gegangen | er würde geschlafen haben/sie würde gegangen sein |

None of these forms imply any grammatical tense. They can all be used when speaking about past, present, or future events (though of course, the perfect aspect means completion at any of those time planes).

I can only speculate why anybody would speak of «Futur» when it comes to the *würde* periphrasis of the conjunctive preterite. I guess it is because the verb commonly used in the periphrasis, *würde*, is a form of the verb *werden*, which is used in the construction *werde* + infinitive, traditionally known as «Futur». The use of the label «Futur» for that form is, I believe, a remnant from the time when every grammar of every language was described in the categories of the Latin grammar. The German *werde* + infinitive construction is, however, not a future tense. When speaking about future events, its use is not required. Its use does not mean that an event takes place in the future. The meaning of *werde* + infinitive is better understood as a modal construction expressing that at the moment of speaking, the factuality of the event cannot (yet) be ascertained.

Comment: That's a completely normal form: "Wärest Du zum Supermarkt gegangen, würdest Du auch das Chaos dort gesehen haben." But that arguably is not futur at all, but Konjunktiv irrealis der Vergangenheit. Arguably it is better phrased as "... hättest Du auch das Chaos dort gesehen." In my book these two forms are used interchangably, though, the first being the more colloquial version.

Comment: @planetmaker: Don’t you mean «würdest du zum Supermarkt gegangen sein»?  You are right though, the form is regular, toning down the answer accordingly.

Comment: thinking more about this distinction: I think there can be a tiny difference in meaning (though the distinction may vanish at times): the form "gingest Du..." is more expression of disbelief of this action happening on the speaker than "würdest Du gehen" which is expresses a possibility which might or might not happen (and accordingly in the past tense approximately expressing a belief of "was never an option" vs. "was an option".